# Bounding the number of primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, logarithms, distribution-of-primes

I have to prove that $$\pi(x)>c\log \log x$$
for some absolute constant $c$. So far I have proven that the nth prime $p_n$ will always be less than $2^{2^{n}}+1$, which I feel maybe helpful.

Comment: If $p_n\leq 2^{2^n}$ then $n\leq \pi(2^{2^n})$ and by letting $2^{2^n}=x$...

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow- this means that $2^{2^n}$ will be less than the number of primes proceeding it, now my I just take the log of both sides to get it into the form I need?

Comment: $p_n\leq 2^{2^n}$ implies $n=\pi(p_n)\leq \pi(2^{2^n})$. By letting $2^{2^n}=x$ we get $n=\log_2 \log_2 x$ and $\pi(x)\geq \log_{2}\log_{2}(x)$.